# How to remove group and others permission in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, security, permissions, file-management, group-policy

How to remove group and others permissions in Windows 10, such that end result will be similar to `chmod go= -R ~`?  I can execute the Linux command even though I am not a superuser/admin and I am not admin on the Windows account.

Comment: You cannot modify which group a user is in without being an Administrator on Windows.  What you describe is impossible if you are not on an Administrator account.  This question is poorly researched.

Answer (score 1):

> How to remove group and others permission in Windows 10 .... (I am not
> admin)

You MUST be Admin (that is, member of Administrators) to do what you are trying to do.

[Change permissions](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/88436-change-permissions-objects-users-groups-windows-10-a.html)

> When you are a member of a group (ex: "Administrators") that is
> associated with an object, you have some ability to manage the
> permissions on that object. For those objects you own ***(that is your
> own computer and your own userid)***, you have full control.

Comment: I'm not admin on Linux, but still can execute the mentioned command.

Comment: The tag is Windows 10 and changes to Permissions and Groups requires Windows 10 Admin.

Comment: I added an informative article for you to read.